# Looking for employee checklist app

Tags: ios

I am a supervisor of student employees and we are looking for an app that will make tracking employee progress easier on us as well as our employees.  What we are wanted to do is create checklists that can be completed by our employees, and then submitted via email.  This will let us know when tasks are complete, as well as provide our employees with an easy way to track their progress.  We would like to avoid multiple accounts for each employee or any online registration.  Does anyone know of an app that can do this?

Comment: Could you give us details of software that you need? You can add required operating system, free or paid software, or even experiences the previous software that you've used before. Please, refer to this guide http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information